# Cargo linker error under MacOS, library "is not mach-o or llvm bitcode for architecture arm64"

Tags: macos, rust, clang

I'm having some problems executing the tests in a rust library I've written. `cargo check` and `cargo build` run without issue, but when I try to execute the program I get a linker error I'm having some trouble deciphering.

```
$ cargo test -v
       Fresh unicode-xid v0.2.2
       Fresh cfg-if v1.0.0
       Fresh ppv-lite86 v0.2.16
       Fresh ryu v1.0.9
       Fresh itoa v1.0.1
       Fresh libc v0.2.112
       Fresh proc-macro2 v1.0.36
       Fresh quote v1.0.14
       Fresh getrandom v0.2.3
       Fresh gmp-mpfr-sys v1.4.7
       Fresh az v1.2.0
       Fresh syn v1.0.84
       Fresh rand_core v0.6.3
       Fresh serde_derive v1.0.133
       Fresh rand_chacha v0.3.1
       Fresh serde v1.0.133
       Fresh rand v0.8.4
       Fresh serde_json v1.0.74
       Fresh rug v1.14.0
Compiling discus-backend v0.1.0
Running `rustc --crate-name discus_backend --edition=2018 src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C split-debuginfo=unpacked -C debuginfo=2
--test -C metadata=c71e1fcdeaefee0d -C extra-filename=-c71e1fcdeaefee0d --out-dir /Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/
incremental -L dependency=/Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps --extern rand=/Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps/librand-fdf71b69660f64cc.rlib --extern rug=/Users/al
ex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps/librug-5dfded8345f82a31.rlib --extern serde=/Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps/libserde-3fe66fa2e4f801a1.rlib --extern serde_json=/Users
/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps/libserde_json-fa4a5cc9d88aac71.rlib -L native=/Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/build/gmp-mpfr-sys-baf189f7359fe85f/out/lib
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-arch" "arm64" [..ommited a wall of text..]
  = note: ld: in /Users/alex/Documents/PhD/discus/backend/target/debug/deps/libgmp_mpfr_sys-fc4a05e05df117d3.rlib(randclr.o), archive member 'randclr.o' with length 496 is not mach-o or llvm bitcode for architucture arm64
          clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


warning: `discus-backend` (lib test) generated 9 warnings (9 duplicates)
error: could not compile `discus-backend` due to previous error; 9 warnings emitted
```

I suspect this is some problem with my development environment on MacOS, I've recently migrated from Linux to MacOS, it worked fine on Linux and a continuous integration set up on GitLab runs the tests without a problem.

```
$ cc -v
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
$ ld -v
ld -v                                                                    ~
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-711
BUILD 21:57:24 Nov 17 2021
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 13.0.0, (clang-1300.0.29.30) (static support for 27, runtime is 27)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 13.0.0 (tapi-1300.0.6.5)
```

Attempted using different `rustup` installers, via the official rust installation script, nixpkg, and homebrew. Same problem with each.

If anyone can offer any advice it would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: M1 Mac?………………….

Comment: Yep!...........

Comment: Are certain you are not attempting to link onto an x86_64 object?

Comment: I think I'm not, although I am very suspicious of Rosetta 2. I suspect something is definitely running through it. Any tips on debugging which objects are arm and which are x86?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [`x86_64-apple-darwin`](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html) version of rust.

I found this method [from](https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/issues/956), and  it solved my problem.